# Position fixed element on ios safari?

Tags: html, mobile-safari

I'm trying to position a bouncing swipe down arrow as part of a mobile form.

[Form demo](http://demo.meydjer.com/lastform/lastform/4)

Because this is an off the shelf type form plugin, any HTML i insert gets inserted right after the opening  tag.

CSS

```
.downArrow{z-index:1;position: fixed;bottom: 45%;left: 65%;}
```

HTML

```
<div class="downArrow bounce" id="helper" style="display:block;">
  <p class="downHelper">swipe</p>
</div>
```

[Swipe down pen](https://codepen.io/itshush/pen/gQMLew)

Now this works just fine across other browsers; but on iOS safari the element does not show up. Really stuck on this, here is what i have tried thus far:

- Changing Z-Index: If i jack the z index up I'll see the element but nothing else on the page
- Adding -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0); to the wrapper, no changes